Connecting to the Socket.io server
I have a website on nextjs and I'm trying to implement a calling function using simplepeer. As I understand it, I need to have a signaling server for this and I created it based on socket.io. I also rented a cloud server with Ubuntu on it to launch my website. Everything works within the local network, but when transferred to the server, connecting to the server on socket.io becomes impossible. I have SSL certificates and a domain (they are connected and the site as a whole is accessible from the global network)
I'm sorry, but then I replaced my domain with "domain"
On a rented server I use nginx and proxying. Here's the configuration:
server {
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name domain; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /signal {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;     
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

Here is the configuration of the signaling server (after the presented ones there are simply event handlers):
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem')
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(options);
const io = new Server(httpsServer, {
path: '/socket.io/',
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

And finally, the connection to the signal server itself:
useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io('domain/socket.io/', {
      transports: ['websocket'],
      secure: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });

    setSocket(newSocket);

    newSocket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Socket.IO Connected!');
    });
};

Waiting: successful connection.
Reality: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.ru/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:"
I also tried writing various prefixes before the connection address like wss or https

I'm sorry, I didn't indicate that I replaced "location /signal {" with "location /socket.io/ {". But still, it still doesn't work

I think your proxy passes /socket.io to the root of your server running at localhost:3001. You should change the proxy_pass to pass the request to localhost:3001/socket.io. To quickly check if I am right try to connect from your frontend using /socket.io/socket.io. If this doesn't work try to make a middleware that logs all incoming requests on '*' and see where it lands.

Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help me. Perhaps I understand this too poorly
